# While trying to integrate a ZOHO API in my web site.Zoho API Call working in POST Man tool,but in code not working why?

Tags: postman, php-curl, zoho

Postman request working but Php curl request not working. I used Postman auto generated code.

Zoho API CAll -> https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token in postman tool

```
 Result -> as JSON


 {
"access_token": "1000.0c**********************7.********8",
"api_domain": "https://www.zohoapis.com",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600
}
```

PHP code here from Postman tool

```
<?php

 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('refresh_token' => 
'1000.3ea1636f577f421e71220d53d84f1fa0.df6c6323fd404daa568d364b0367756e','client_id' => '1000.N13Y5EYD42USXIH88PHCFB22GRLPDH','client_secret' => 'eec6c737dac644256b53b58d9610614319997025f0','redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8080/plugins/thanthiarchival/home.html','grant_type' => 'refresh_token'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Cookie: b266a5bf57=57c7a14afabcac9a0b9dfc64b3542b70; iamcsr=a8d8b288-7040-4873-b04b-306620bf8f81; _zcsr_tmp=a8d8b288-7040-4873-b04b-306620bf8f81'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

 curl_close($curl);
 echo $response;
  ?>
```

This php-curl code is generated from postman tool.Kindly suggest something.

Comment: I had changes in code for find the erorr.

Comment: $curl_error = curl_error($curl);
echo ($curl_error);

For that i get some error message
->

"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Answer (score 0):

To help see what is going on in the PHP-CURL request and debug, try setting Curl to verbose:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
...
CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
...
));
```

Answer (score 0):

if add the following code my ssl certificate problem solved

```
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
```